# Run python function on groups of rows of dataframe column, return dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this df:

```
data = {'material': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'week': [5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8], 'demand': [20,5,0,15,4,3,8,9,15,74,12,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I have a function that iterates over an input list, calculates the mean and removes the first element from the list. I use this function to calculate the mean demand from the last 4,3,2... weeks

```
def get_means(input_list):
    means = []
    weeks = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
        mean = sum(input_list) / len(input_list) # calculate the mean from input list and store in mean
        input_list = input_list[1:] # remove first value from input list
        means.append(mean) # append mean to list means
        weeks.append(len(input_list)+1) # append number of weeks used to calculate mean to list weeks
    return (weeks, means)
```

I am missing the skill to "scale" that function. Right now I call the function on just one material from the df, in this example the first material (df is always sorted by material-week)

```
input_list = df[df["material"]==df.material.unique()[0]]["demand"]
```

which gives me

```
out = get_means(input_list)
print(out)

([4, 3, 2], [10.0, 6.666666666666667, 7.5])
```

I would like to call the function for every unique material from the df. The output should ideally be a dictionary that contains materials, weeks and means.

Would be great if someone could point me into the right direction here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty dictionary and keep adding to it for each unique value

```
l = df.material.unique()
d = {}
for i in l:
    d[i] = get_means(df.loc[df['material'].eq(i),'demand'])
```

---

```
print(d)

{1: ([4, 3, 2], [10.0, 6.666666666666667, 7.5]),
 2: ([4, 3, 2], [6.0, 6.666666666666667, 8.5]),
 3: ([4, 3, 2], [26.0, 29.666666666666668, 7.5])}
```